# How to detect keyboard type switch in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I wanna know when the user types a space in numeric keyboard in order to switch to default keyboard (with letters). I would listen the keyboard type switch then save it as a state. Any idea?

Comment: could you clarify your question a bit more? Do you mean, a keyboardType={'numeric'} because there is no space in numeric keyboard as far as i know.

Comment: I need to know on which type of keyboard the user is typing on. It could be 'numeric' or 'default' for instance. I can't not access from keyboardType because I think this prop doesn't update when the user changes the keyboard type manually. So the solution would be to put a listener on native keyboard and get the type while user is taping a key. You see what I mean?

Comment: by numeric you mean when the user presses '123' labeled key on the keyboard, or the actual numeric keyboard?